# How to fix the this issue in Text Input Layout?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-textinputlayout

Im having trouble putting the eye toggle on top of the edit text in text input layout.

Can you help me fix this? I want to finish my project. Thank you!

Here is the XML file:

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

```
            android:id="@+id/PasswordEye"
            style="@style/NoBottomLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/enter_password"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/textbox_background"
            android:textColorHint="@color/textbox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/primary">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp"
                android:ems="15"/>
```

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

here is the output:

[image]